# How do I create a new column in my dataframe based on a date condition, within Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

How do I create a column in my dataframe called 'Declined Or Hired', where a '1' is input into each row where the '(Declined - Reason) Or Hire' column starts with "Offer Declined -..." and the 'Date' column is between January and March 2022. I started with the code below, which works for my first condition, but not sure how to add the date condition to it.

`df['Declined Or Hired'] = (df[''(Declined - Reason) Or Hire'].str.startswith('Offer Declined',  na = False ).astype(int))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a second condition:

```
df['Declined Or Hired'] = (df['(Declined - Reason) Or Hire'].str.startswith('Offer Declined',  na=False)
                           & pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
                               .between(pd.Timestamp('2022-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2022-03-31'))
                           ).astype(int))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works...I tried to add a third condition to your code which said 
```& df['Job ID'] != ['']```
....i.e when a row in the column "Job ID" is not blank, as my real dataset is larger, than the one shown. However the code then just accepted two conditions. Do you know where I should be adding this condition to your code, so that all three conditions work pls?

Comment: You can use a number of conditions but ensure to respect operator precedence. Use `& (df['Job ID'] != '')` or `& df['Job ID'].ne('')`

Comment: Okay, that works fine. But I think my issue is that when I have another date field like ```& (df['Datefield_2'] != ' ')``` and I want to make make sure that this condition is also satisfied, I am not sure where to put this code. The full code only takes the first condition and one of the date conditions. Hence I think I am placing this date condition in the wrong place?